# Decompiling Adobe AIR applications

Tags: air, decompiling

Are there tools for decompiling Adobe AIR applications?
I want to check how do they work on the apps I have made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for ;)
http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/index.htm

Comment: Sothink no longer supports modern SWF files.

Answer (score 20):

Packaged AIR files (those with .air extension) are ZIP files. You can use any ZIP program to pull them apart.

However, AIR apps can be written in Flash, Flex or HTML/JavaScript. If the app you want to look at is not the latter, you will need a Flash or Flex decompiler.

Answer (score 4):

Sothink SWF Decompiler claimed the file was corrupt.

What worked for me, was **JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler** which had the added benefit of being open source and completely free.
https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler/releases