# Programmatically read Adobe game variables / interact with the game / game bot

Tags: adobe, hook, bots, packet-sniffers, game-development

Basicly, I'm trying to read a game's chat and catch actions from the user.

Here is the image which I will explain the situation with :

[image]

1: I took a message in the chat

2: I tryed to find it in the game's memory with Cheat-Engine

3: By examining every addresses where it was found, I ended up to this one, which contains the chat formated with what seems to be html..
That part is only the bottom part of the chat. (I see the rest of it if I scroll up)

So, I asked myself how could I read game variable to interact with the game.

Another thing I'm trying to achieve is to catch the user's actions so I can display some information in a winform.

I've just read about packet sniffing, it seems interesting for what I'm trying to do.

I tryed to read packets going in and out of this app with WireShark. Every action in game was sending a few packets, but I couldn't read them as they were just a bunch of weird characters. I tryed to decrypt them using a few methods I got on WireShark's forum without success. I was asking myself, even if I could see them in Wireshark, how am I gonna do that programmatically..

There is certainly a good way to do this, as we often see bots in this game.
Considering the number of bots playing "in team", I'm pretty sure they do not use clicks, but they run something in background that sends requests.

**How do you make such a bot that fight, talk, interact with players automatically?**

This game is Dofus, powered by Adobe Air.

I usually program with c++ and c#, but I was wondering what's the best way to do this.

I need a **kick in the right direction**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe trying a tcp/ip listner control (or use tcplistner class in c#) in your c# project with the appropriate port to catch requests (& responses).  Information sended could be compressed so you may want to try some standard algo.

[Did you try reverse engineer the AIR app ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711187/decompiling-adobe-air-applications)

Comment: Thanks François! I'm currently looking further into capturing/sending packets to the game.

Comment: Reverse engineer won't work since it's a server based game, flash is used on client side to render the game.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm now playing with SharpPcap library to read/send packets. So far I am able to get packets sent from/to the game :D The hard part is to determine what means what in the "fonction" part of the packet since there are only hex codes. Anyways I'm testing that :P